# Total rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 8874 rows in excel and when I read in python and check number of rows by [df.info] OR [df.shape] I get mixed answers.Shape command gives 7313 while info gives 7313 and 8874.

**Example 1:**

```
df.shape
(7313, 83)
```

**Example 2:**

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 7313 entries, 2 to 8874
Data columns (total 83 columns):
```

What is actual command to see total number of rows including duplicates, null etc.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your data frame has 7313 rows when you read it in with pandas. `df.shape` will give you `(# rows, # cols)`. `df.shape` includes all duplicate rows and rows with null values.

When you use `df.info()`, it tells you a bit more information. `Int64Index: 7313 entries, 2 to 8874` tells you that you have `7313` rows that have integer labels. The index (essentially row labels) for your data frame has a starting value of 2 and an ending value of 8874.

Here's an example with a small data frame

```
print(df)
```

Output:

```
              var  var2
my_row_names           
38              1     1
1               2     2
2               2     2
3               3     3
55656         888     4
```

Then we can look at the info

```
df.info()
```

And see a similar output to yours

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 38 to 55656
Data columns (total 2 columns):
var     5 non-null int64
var2    5 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 120.0 bytes
```